# minus specify elements in 2D array numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy

Assume there is a matrix X, a mask and a vector y

```
>>> X
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> mask
array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> y
[8, 9, 10]
```

I want each row of X where mask is true minus y. so i get the result

```
>>> x[mask].reshape(4,3)-y
array([[-7, -7, -7],
       [-4, -3, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 4,  4,  4]])
```

But i want to keep the X a 4*4 matrix. That means where the mask is False, the value of X should not be changed. what should i do? Thanks.

Comment: What if some row of `mask` doesn't have exactly three `True` values? What's the expected output?

Comment: That won't work.  Because y has 3 values. if the number of columns is not the same as y, there will be some mistake.

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,4) (3,) 
This error is each row of mask has 2 False values.

Comment: Frankly, I want to each element in the row where the mask is True minus the element in the row where the mask is False.  But the dimension is changed so i want to figure out an efficient way to solve it.

Comment: Can we assume each row of mask would have exactly the same number of True values as there are number of elements in y?

Comment: yes. absolutely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches could be suggested for in-place edits.

**Approach #1 :** Boolean-index into `X`. Reshape it to have same number of elements as number of elements in `y`. Subtract `y` from it, thus leveraging `broadcasting`. Finally index into `X` with the same mask and assign flattened subtracted values.
 -

```
X[mask] = (X[mask].reshape(X.shape[0],-1) - y).ravel()
```

**Approach #2 :** Resize `y` to have same number of elements as the number of `True` elements in `mask` and simply subtract from the masked places in `X` -

```
X[mask] -= np.resize(y,mask.sum())
```

Sample runs -

```
In [55]: X    # Input array
Out[55]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

# Using approach #1
In [56]: X[mask] = (X[mask].reshape(X.shape[0],-1) - y).ravel()

In [57]: X  # Changed input array
Out[57]: 
array([[ 0, -7, -7, -7],
       [-4,  5, -3, -3],
       [ 0,  0, 10,  1],
       [ 4,  4,  4, 15]])

In [59]: X   # Input array
Out[59]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

# Using approach #2
In [60]: X[mask] -= np.resize(y,mask.sum())

In [61]: X    # Changed input array
Out[61]: 
array([[ 0, -7, -7, -7],
       [-4,  5, -3, -3],
       [ 0,  0, 10,  1],
       [ 4,  4,  4, 15]])
```